# Any Way To Speed up this Loop?

Tags: php, performance

is there any way to speed up this function? 
it takes too much time and sometimes not working

```
<?php 
$json = file_get_contents('http://xxxxxxxx/players.json');
$data = json_decode($json,true);
for ($i=0; $i< count($data); $i++) 

{
    $temp = explode(":",$data[$i]['identifiers'][0]);
    $json2 = file_get_contents('http://api.steampowered.com/ISteamUser/GetPlayerSummaries/v0002/?key=XXXXXXXXXXXXX&steamids=' . hexdec($temp[1]) . '');
    $data2 = json_decode($json2);
    $playerData = ''. $data2->response->players[0]->personaname . ',' . $data2->response->players[0]->avatarfull .'';
    echo($playerData);
    echo "<br>";
}
?>
```

Comment: "Sometimes not working" what do you mean? "Speed up" how fast is it now?

Comment: You're requesting data from an API on each loop. Considering you're dealing with a 3rd party service, there's probably no way if they don't have a way to get multiple users at once.

Comment: move `count($data)` to before the loop and store it in a variable. _nbut I doubt you notice the change

Comment: It looks like your steampowered API call can return multiple users at once judging by the name `steamids`. Why are you doing one at a time? I'm surprised you're not being rate limited.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can fetch more than 1 ID at a time. According to the documentation, you can use a comma between user IDs and can fetch up to 100 at a time.

`Comma-delimited list of 64 bit Steam IDs to return profile information for. Up to 100 Steam IDs can be requested.` https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/Steam_Web_API#GetPlayerSummaries_.28v0002.29

After your first $json, loop through and add the identifiers into an array. Then create a single call with $json2 where you implode the IDs from $json with a comma between each.

If you expect more than 100 IDs then you will have to make more calls.